# Evaluating complicated limits correctly

Tags: functions, symbolic

Let's say I have defined some function:

`a[x_] = x^2 Log[x^2]`.

If I try to evaluate `a[0]` Mathematica will complain that it is indeterminate, but if I evaluate `Limit[a[x],x->0]` I get the correct answer.

My problem is that my function is a function of very many variables that I wish to send to zero, and it contains a few instances of the form `(x^2 + y^2 + ...)Log[x^2 + y^2 + ...]`. (But not all of exactly the same form, so there is no obvious change of variables I can do.)

If I try to take the limit `Limit[f[x,y,...],{x->0, y->0, ...}]`, Mathematica will take a very long time to give me the answer, and if I try `f[0,0,...]`, I get `Indeterminate`. However from inspection I know that most of the terms should go to zero and the final result will be finite.

I'm wondering if there is a fast way to get Mathematica to evaluate these limits correctly?

Comment: Are you asking about automatically locating and removing removable singular points? The automatically locating part is very hard in general.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) Log[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)] /. 
 e_*Log[e_] :> Limit[e*Log[e] /. e :> temp, temp -> 0]

Comment: Not likely to be a fast way, especially when limit exists and is neither infinite nor zero. Methods for finding these in the multivariate setting tend to use heavy computational machinery, and therefore can be slow.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
Limit[f[x, y] /. {x -> s x, y -> s y}, s -> 0]
```

For example:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x Log[x] + (x^2+y^2+z^2)Log[x^2+y^2+z^2] + x + 1
Limit[f[x, y, z] /. {x -> s x, y -> s y, z -> s z}, s -> 0]
```

> 1

Comment: This gives a candidate value (which is the correct value, when the limit exists). Proving that it is path independent takes more work.

Comment: Is this faster? It doen't seem to be for me.....If we can assume the limit exists, which the OP seems to imply, then `Limit[f[s, s, s], s -> 0]` should be faster (it is in this example).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps to define your function by `Piecewise`:

```
b[x_] := Piecewise[{
   {0., -10 $MachineEpsilon <= x <= 10 $MachineEpsilon}
   },
  x^2 Log[x^2]]
b[0.]
```

> 0.

Answer (score 0):

This won't suffice for symbolic analysis in general, but it works for computation:

```
aa[x_] := x^2 Log[x^2]
a[x_] := With[ {ap = Quiet[aa[x]]}, 
  If[ap =!= Indeterminate, ap, Limit[aa[y], y -> x]]]
```